# Saving the username in MVC2 + EF4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4, httpcontext

I am working on a simple MVC2 project with EF4. I am also using Repository pattern which is instantiated in the controller's constructor. I have 34 tables each with CreatedBy and LastModifiedBy fields that needs to populated when the record is saved.

Do you have other ideas on how to pass the username from the controller to the entity other than this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(){

     Record rec = new Record();
     TryUpdateModel(rec);
     rec.CreatedBy = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
     rec.LastModifiedBy = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name; 
     repository.Save();

     return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom model binder that would set these two properties before action gets invoked.

Something like this:

```
public class CustomModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {
        protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
        {
            if ((propertyDescriptor.Name == "CreatedBy") || (propertyDescriptor.Name == "LastModifiedBy"))
            {
                //set value
            }
            base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I ended up implementing your approach. In my custom model binder, I am only setting the LastModifiedBy field. In the override of the EF SaveChanges method, I am checking the EntityState.Added and pass the LastModifiedBy to CreatedBy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap this in repository. If all your entities share same fields you can define bass entity with those fields and derive other entities from this one (Table per concrete class hiearchy).

Then you can define base class for your repository like:

```
// Other repositories derive from this repository
// BaseEntity is parent of all your entities and it has your shared fields
public abstract class BaseRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
  ....
  public void Save(IIdentity user, T entity)
  {
     entity.CreatedBy = user.Name;
     entity.LastModifiedBy = user.Name;
     ...
  }
}
```

You can further improve this code by passing IIdentity directly to repository constructor or better by passing some custom Identity provider to repository constructor. Default provider implementation for web application will return identity from HttpContext.

Comment: Using this solution, where would you put validation for these two fields?

Comment: @frennky: Validation? Validation takes place elsewhere - you must know that user is allowed to modify or create object before you call the save method. For example you can use Authorize attribute on action.

Comment: No, not authorization but validation, for example check if username is valid to be saved (it could be longer than db filed etc.). Where would you put that logic?

Comment: @frennky: If it is some business logic validation I will use it outside of repository. If it is validation related to persistance (like field length) I don't see a problem in including this validation directly to Save method.

Comment: Ladislav Mrnka, your solution will also work but @frennky's solution is lesser change on my part, not to mention I dont know how to implement "Table per concrete class" in "model first" EF4.